# Ember: One-to-one relationship (DS.belongsTo) doesn't set inverse

Tags: javascript, ember.js

tl;dr: on [this page](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/bisecofo/4/edit?js,output), click "yes" - `parent.id` of "Great..." is not set. Click "maybe" and then "yes" again - now `parent.id` is `0`. Why didn't it get set the first time?

Here's [my code](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/bisecofo/4/edit?js,output).

I'm making a kind of [decision tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree) where each node (a `card`) has multiple choices for children. I defined this relationship like this:

```
App.Card = DS.Model.extend
  child: DS.belongsTo('card', inverse: 'parent')
  parent: DS.belongsTo('card', inverse: 'child')
  question: DS.attr('string')
  answers: DS.hasMany('answer', async: true, inverse: 'card')
```

I set the child in `CardController#answer`:

```
answer: (answer) ->
  console.log "answering"
  @get('model').set('child', answer.get('card'))
```

And that works just fine, but it doesn't set the *inverse* relationship.

You can verify this by clicking the blue `yes` button: the "Hi John..." card's `child.id` changes to `1`, but the child card's `parent.id` (the "Great..." card) is null.

But here's the weird part: if you toggle "Hi John..."'s child a few times (click `maybe`, then back to `yes`), then the child's `parent.id` is set!

Why isn't the child card's `parent` being set the first time?

Answer (score 0):

From IRC user `alexspeller` from `#emberjs` on freenode.net:

> it's probably a bug but it will probably be fixed by the [Single Source of Truth] branch

From Ember's [THE ROAD TO EMBER DATA 1.0](http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/03/18/the-road-to-ember-data-1-0.html#toc_a-single-source-of-truth):

> TL;DR Ember Data 1.0 is coming soon. We have a few last features to land before we can confidently make guarantees around not breaking the API. Specifically:
>
> 1. A guarantee that if one side of a two-way relationship changes, the other side will remain in sync, even if it hasn't loaded yet.

So it's probably a bug in Ember Data 1.0. I'm going to explore the alternative Ember data store, [Ember Model](https://github.com/ebryn/ember-model), which is more stable and supports one-to-one relations.